# In JQM can i get a separate event for a listview and a checkbox inside listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

In Jquery mobile, I have created a checkbox inside a listview. I want to separate the two events, as when the user only checks the checkbox an event fires. And onClicking a list item, a different event takes place.

How can i achieve this in JQM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a problem, take a look at my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QXJrk/

When you click on a checkbox only it's  click will trigger and when you click on a listview element only it will trigger it's own action.

I don't know how you managed to create your checkbox over listview implementation but if listview is triggered when you click a checkbox then you also need to do this in checkbox click event:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, i guess this should help me out... u have been a great help

Comment: Hi Gajotres, just one query. I am creating the dynamic listview. So as per your jsfiddle link checked="checked" attribute is not working. What do i need to do? I tried $("#checkbox-0").checkboxradio("refresh"); but it did not work

Comment: I didn't understand you. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I got the solution on a separate post that i had written. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446907/the-checked-attribute-of-checkbox-does-not-get-enabled-if-the-html-is-created thanks a lot for all your help